# Is it possible to revert log history in subversion?

Tags: svn

When you revert to a previous version of a file in svn and then check it in, the svn log will not get rid of the log entries after the revision you reverted to, but will just add a new log entry for the change you made back to the reverted file.

My question: Is there any possible way that the log itself can be reverted so that entries are actually lost?  I would hope not, but I just want to find out for a certainty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With SVN's admin tools you can dump a repository, filter out certain revisions, and import it back in again.

However, this is laborious and not for the faint of heart, and it is this way intentionally. The purpose of SVN is to *preserve* history, however twisted, and not to lose it.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm a little baffled right now because I changed two lines of code on Friday.  I know it has to be a human error on my part, but I just feel like I'm taking crazy pills because not only do I seem to remember checking it in, the change is not even on my own computer anymore.  Thankfully 2 lines of code is not a big deal to lose but I don't like having memories of things that I didn't actually do...

Comment: @BrandonMoore: I'm not sure whether we have a http://psychology.stackexchange.com yet. `:)`

Answer (score 4):

The only way is to dump the repository and to reimport it by filtering some entries. So in short: it's impossible. Once something is committed it'll stay in the repository ad vitam aeternam.